# jmeter - loop controller and loop count differences

Tags: jmeter

I have a simple scenario:

- log in

  perform search1

  perform search2

  perform search3

Now, is there a difference between those two approaches

1. 10 threads, 1 loop, login + loop controller (3 loops) for search

   10 threads, 3 loops, once only controller for login + search

In theory the behavior should be the same, i.e. 10 users logging in and running three searches, right?
Or is there a difference?
Which approach is better?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No difference in your case.

This scenario is simple, for more complicated case, when you can have much more cycles in single thread group 1st case may be more preferable because of handling looping of this part of sampler doesn't require touching thread group params... as well it's completely subjective.

Comment: Thanks Alies. So I ran both version of the same scenario and it seems that the second approach is much slower than the first one. The number of requests is the same in both cases, but the response times are much slower when the thread group loop count is higher than 1. The Active Threads over Time distribution is pretty much the same. Any idea why the second version runs slower?

Comment: Looking into the set of test-runs results for both scenarios I see no difference in response times nevertheless - refer Aggregate Report results e.g.: Average / 90% line / Throughput values at least. Active Threads over Time seems to be something a bit different - that depends more on scenario / test structure.

Comment: You were right the first time. It seems the problem was introduced by the data file element, when it was included at the high level it worked for the second approach, but the first one always took one value for the whole loop controller, ie. search was done 3 times for the same value. I had to put the CSV config under the loop controller to make it read different values for each loop count.

Bootom line. There should be little difference between those two approaches. Thanks!